# Как сделать проверку(валидацию) в зависимости от числового значения <tr> в таблице

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется таблица, у каждого поставщика своя электронная почта, при запросе в ячейке "Запросить стоимость" выходит модальное окно с формой запроса, где пользователь должен внести имя, телефон, почту и выбрать поставщика(в таблице идет просто нумерация поставщиков). В зависимости от выбора поставщика отправится запрос на определенный адрес. Сейчас валидация в форме проходит только для обязательного выбора поставщика, но если пользователь выбирает не того поставщика запрос уходит не по назначению. Подскажите можно ли сделать валидацию по ячейке поставщик в строке и выбором поставщика в форме. Я так понимаю это можно реализовать через .js чтобы если пользователь выбрал не того поставщика выходила ошибка "Выбран не тот поставщик".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="[[*pagetitle]]">
    <input type="hidden" name="link" value="[[*uri]]">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Как вас зовут? *" value="[[+fi.name-zv]]" name="name-zv" class="input_text form-control"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email *" name="email" value="[[!+fi.email]]" id="email" class="phone-zv form-control"/>
    <input type="text" data-mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99" placeholder="Контактный телефон *" name="phone-zv" value="[[+fi.phone-zv]]" id="phone-zv" class="phone-zv form-control"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Сообщение *" name="message" value="[[!+fi.message]]" id="message" class="phone-zv form-control"/>
    <select name="emailselect">
<option value="" selected disabled>Выбрать поставщика</option>
<option value="1" [[!+fi.emailselect:default=`1`:FormItIsSelected=`2`]]>Поставщик 1</option>
<option value="2" [[!+fi.emailselect:default=`2`:FormItIsSelected=`3`]]>Поставщик 2</option>
<option value="3" [[!+fi.emailselect:default=`3`:FormItIsSelected=`4`]]>Поставщик 3</option>
```

Поля отмеченные * обязательны для заполнения